# Precedence of `in` and `==` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, operator-precedence

Suppose I have the following line of code:

```
print("valley" in "hillside" == False)
```

Since the precedence of `in` and `==` is equivalent in Python, I expected the operations to be performed from left to right, producing `True` as the output.

However, in actuality, when I run this line of code, I get `False`.

I have noticed that adding brackets around `"valley" in "hillside"` results in `True` as the output but I don't seem to understand why it's necessary in the first place...

Comment: Not really. According to the documentation, `==` and `in` have the same precedence.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation also describes the chaining in quite some detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `in` and `==` are comparison operators, so the parser treats

```
print("valley" in "hillside" == False)
```

the same as

```
print("valley" in "hillside" and "hillside" == False)
```

See the section on [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in the Python language reference for more details, in particular this note:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Comment: That makes sense- Thanks!